# Match the elements of two lists based on a pattern with a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I need the code that will give those results based on those 2 lists.
The number of items in the lists in greater in reality than in the example.

```py
list1 = ['a','a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']


result_a = ['a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
result_b = ['b', 'g', 'h']
result_c = ['c', 'i']
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code and explain any issues you had with it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic that produces those results?

Comment: You should make a dictionary whose keys are the elements of `list1`. Each value is a list of the elements of `list2` that correspond to the key.

Comment: I *think* the request is 'for every occurrence of an item in list1, pick that many items from list 2. So 3 `a`'s gives `a, d, e, f`, 2 `b`'s gives `b, g, h`, 1 `c` gives `c, i`. At least that's what my answer assumes!

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
result_a, result_b, result_c = (
    [group[0][0]] + [t[1] for t in group] 
    for group in (
        list(group) 
        for _, group in itertools.groupby(
            zip(list1, list2), lambda t: t[0]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please check question "The number of items in the lists in greater in reality than in the example."

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest to understand code is to use `Counter` to count the number of each item in `list1` then slice that many items from `list2`, moving the start and end point as you go:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['a','a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

start = 0
for letter, count in Counter(list1).items():
    # Add the letter from list1 to the new list
    l = [letter]
    end = start + count
    # Add the slice of list2 to the new list
    l.extend(list2[start:end])
    print(l)
    # Move the start position on list2
    start = end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to pair up the corresponding elements of the two lists. Use the value from `list1` as the key of a dictionary, and add the elements of `list2` to the corresponding value.

```
results = {}
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    if key in results:
        results[key].append(value)
    else:
        results[key] = [key, value]
```

Comment: I like using a dict to group them, but what if `list2` has elements that are also in `list1`?

Comment: @Samwise Why would that be a problem? Nothing in the question suggests the need to remove duplicates.

Comment: `for k,v in zip(list1,list2):
    results.setdefault(k,[k]).append(v)` this does the same I don't know which of both are considered *pythonic*

Comment: ah sorry, it's not list2/list1 conflicts that are the issue, it's if you have repeats in `list1` that are non-contiguous.

Comment: @Ch3steR I knew it was possible to use `setdefault` or `defaultdict`, I'm not just fluent with those idioms so I use `if/else`.

Comment: @Samwise The question doesn't go into detail, I assumed that order is not relevant.